# Woocommerce Add To Cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out how can I show a suggestion page once a user click on the button 'Add To cart'.

I want to show related products as Amazon does.

I do not know how to register the Event and redirect to a template once clicked the button.

Any idea how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default [Cross-sells by WooCommerce](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/related-products-up-sells-and-cross-sells/). The options would then be shown in the cart page. Clicking on Add to Cart can lead the customer to the cart page after the product has been added. That setting can be found in your general settings of WooCommerce to ensure it does that.